# Auth middleware not calling stub - NodeJS, sinon

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, sinon

Similar questions have been asked before & I have looked at & followed them but no luck:

1. [Sinon stub being skipped as node express middleware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53852873/sinon-stub-being-skipped-as-node-express-middleware)
2. [node express es6 sinon stubbing middleware not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41392497/node-express-es6-sinon-stubbing-middleware-not-working)
3. [How to mock middleware in Express to skip authentication for unit test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41995464/how-to-mock-middleware-in-express-to-skip-authentication-for-unit-test)

The general answer I get from these is that the module (`app.js` in my case) should be required **AFTER** the auth middleware method has been stubbed. I have done this, but still calls the original middleware:

**src/app.js**

```
const authentication = require('./authentication')

...

app.use(['/api/users', '/api/groups'], authentication.ensureAuthenticed])

module.exports = app
```

**src/authentication.js**

```
const { isValidAuth } = require('./lib')

exports.ensureAuthenticated = (req, res, next) => {
    ...
}
```

**__helpers__/supertest.js**

```
// This file just calls endpoints with supertest but this is the only file
// that includes 'app'
const app = require('../../src/app')

module.exports = {
    post: {
        ...
    },
    get: {
        ...
    },
    put: {
        ...
    },
    delete: {
        ...
    }
}
```

**users.spec.js**

```
const authentication = require('../../src/authentication')
const authenticationStubs = require('../__stubs__/authentication')

let supertest
let ensureAuthStub

describe('Users', () => {
    before(() => {
        ensureAuthStub = sinon.stub(authentication, 'ensureAuthenticated').callsFake(authenticationStubs.ensureAuthenticated)
        supertest = require('../__helpers__/supertest')
    })

    // tests

    after(() => {
        ensureAuthStub.restore()
    })
})
```

**__stubs__/authentication.js**

```
exports.ensureAuthenticated = (req, res, next) => {
    ...
}
```

In *users.spec.js*, I load in *supertest.js* (which loads in *src/app.js*) **AFTER** the method has been mocked so I am not sure why the original is still being invoked.

I have also attempted to manually clear the cache before mocking but still does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was something to do with having *supertest.js* require *app.js*. I now have *users.spec.js* require the app and pass it it into supertest methods as a param. It now works. Still unsure why though

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution would be using [Rewire](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rewire) instead (or with) Supertest.
Rewire lets you to mock top level components of a module. Though you would need to mock middleware before passing to Supertest.

Comment: Good idea but unfortunately that has not worked either